# React - UI doesn't correspond to the information passed to component

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a match-three game now. The problem is that chips are of another color on the screen, than I pass. Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-dust-94mmx?file=/src/App.js). The console.log shows another colors and the quantity of individual colors also differs.

The method which renders colors

```
  const renderColors = () => {
    const colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet"];
    if (chips.length) {
      return null;
    }
    const chips2 = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < fields; i += 1) {
      let val = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
      if (i > 2) {
        while (chips2[i - 1] === val && chips2[i - 2] === val) {
          val = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
        }
      }
      if (i > 9) {
        while (chips2[i - 10] === val && chips[i - 5] === val) {
          val = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
        }
      }
      chips2.push(val);
    }
    setChips(chips2);
    return chips;
  };
  renderColors();
```

The method, which renders squares with chips

```
const renderSquares = () => {
    const squares = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < fields; i += 1) {
      squares.push(<Square i={i} color={chips[i]} key={i} />);
    }
    return squares;
  };
```

What I did:

1. Checked squares, chips, chips[i] inside  by console.log, they all correspond each other
2. Tried to move chips inside Square and look if it will affect something
3. Restarted server

Will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why did you call `renderColors` where you did, but I'm assuming you wanted to call it when the component first mounts/loads. You should use `useEffect` for that:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Square from "./Square";

export default function App() {
  const [chips, setChips] = useState([]);
  const fields = 45;

  useEffect(() => {
    renderColors();
  });

  const renderColors = () => {
    const colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet"];
    if (chips.length) {
      return null;
    }
    const chips2 = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < fields; i += 1) {
      let val = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
      if (i > 2) {
        while (chips2[i - 1] === val && chips2[i - 2] === val) {
          console.log("3 in row! wow!");
          console.log(
            `${i - 2}: ${chips2[i - 2]}`,
            `${i - 1}: ${chips2[i - 1]}`,
            `${i}: ${val}`
          );
          val = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
          console.log(`changed color to ${val}`);
        }
      }
      if (i > 9) {
        while (chips2[i - 10] === val && chips[i - 5] === val) {
          console.log("3 in column! wow!");
          console.log(
            `${i - 10}: ${chips2[i - 10]}`,
            `${i - 5}: ${chips2[i - 5]}`,
            `${i}: ${val}`
          );
          val = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
        }
      }
      chips2.push(val);
    }
    setChips(chips2);
  };
  const renderSquares = () => {
    console.log(chips);
    const squares = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < fields; i += 1) {
      squares.push(<Square i={i} color={chips[i]} key={i} />);
    }
    return squares;
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="board">{chips.length && renderSquares()}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't know, why that helped, but that helped